# What is diff in apache svn version 6.0.38 vs 6.0.389418

Tags: apache, tomcat, svn, version-control

I want to collect some buggy files.

So, I found data-set that present which file has a bug.

In data set, document said that Tomcat,6.0.389418,org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler file has a bug

In order to get bug file, i visit apache svn repository. And I found archive tomcat version 6_0_38 (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_38)

But I cant get file more detail version (6.0.389418) there is only 6_0_38

Can I think of two versions as the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, you should know that Tomcat 6 has seen its end of life in December 2016, and the latest version that I can find in the archives is 6.0.53.

Based on this alone: Upgrade! First to the latest version in the 6.0 branch, then to a version that actually will continue to get security fixes. I've never seen any problems when upgrading within the same major version - the tomcat developers do a great job keeping their upgrades compatible.

And last, to the letters of your question instead of the spirit: The third digit of Tomcat version numbers is counting up, one by one. There is no 6.0.389418. As Tomcat uses Subversion, and subversion counts up the commits one by one, you might be lucky to find something around commit #389418 or #9418. Note: I've not even looked at their SVN to check if these are legitimate commits in the time that you're referring to (not even what the current commit is).

Comment: I'm trying to collect buggy files to research purpose. So I need java files that referenced in data-set file. The dataset says tomcat version 6.0.389418. Someone advise me that 389418 is revision number.

Comment: When I looked up revision 389418, there is 6.0version trunk. So I think 389418 mean svn revision number. thank you for advise.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it might be quite hard to really nail this build number, but there is also a good chance this is a build you are asking for. Read for explanation.

You are asking for version: 6.0.389418

If you look into this file:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_38/dist.xml

You can learn how build number is being built:

```
<property name="version.number" value="${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.build}.${version.patch}"/>
```

values are taken from:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_38/build.properties.default

```
# ----- Version Control Flags -----
version.major=6
version.minor=0
version.build=38
version.patch=0
version.suffix=
```

So the missing part of your version is `9418` which is should correspond to `${version.build}` or (more unlikely) to `${version.patch}`

In either case it might be not unambiguous, because often there is a build script used which performs multiple actions and as a result, appends its own version at the end of real package. I'd lean towards this explanation, because if this were to be a patch number, there would be some `/patches` directory in SVN, which I don't see in any other directories for more recent development.

But then, there is:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_38/bin/version.sh -> running function from:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_38/bin/catalina.sh

```
elif [ "$1" = "version" ] ; then

    "$_RUNJAVA"   \
      -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" \
      org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

else
```

**Try to download it and run ./bin/version.sh**